# PermissionsAndroid is not showing up in React Native app

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, react-native, permissions

So I change the geolocation, I use Geolocation from `'react-native-geolocation-service'` now. So my problem now is not sure if my codes of PermissionsAndroid is correct because there is no Permission of location dialog is showing. Everytime I press the button "Location permission is not granted" is showing up in the console.log so it means permission is not granted. As I say there is not Permission dialog is showing up.

I want you guys check my codes if where are my mistakes.
These are my codes:

```
hasLocationPermission = () => {
try{
  const granted = PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    {
      title: 'Location Permission',
      message: 'You must to accept this to make it work.'
    }
  )
  if(granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED){
    console.log('Location permission accepted.')
  }else{
    console.log("Location permission denied")
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err)
}
}

getUserLocationHandler = () => {
if(this.hasLocationPermission){
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
      this.setState({
        userLocation: {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0622,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        },
      });
    },
    err => console.log(err),
    {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 15000,
      maximumAge: 10000

    }
  );
}
}

 render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FetchLocation onGetLocation={this.getUserLocationHandler}/>
    <UsersMap userLocation={this.state.userLocation}/>
  </View>
);
}
```

> "FetchLocation" is the Button and the "UsersMap" is the map.
>
> If you guys know how to show up the Permission Dialog before the app open like the Grab app, that would be better. Thank you!
>
> If you want to see something else in my codes or in my build.gradles, feel free to ask. Thank you!

Comment: Have you requested for the user permission at runtime?

Comment: Nope. But I have the "access_fine_location" iny my android manifest.xml

Comment: The permission will show up when they click the button to navigate into their location.

Comment: You need to request runtime permission explicitly for Android 6 and and above

Comment: Read about runtime permission:
 https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid

Comment: How can I do that in my own code?

Comment: Sorry, not a well experienced developer here.

Comment: hey kindly visit here.. may be this will help u ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/68223840/13182553

Answer (score 5):

did you add permission in your AndroidManifest file? like what the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation) said.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Your userdefined Text to request Permission you've added:

```
title: 'Location Permission',
message: 'You must to accept this to make it work.'
```

won't show for the first Permission-Reuquest. But if the user click "deny" and you request again for the Permission in your app, then your Text appears.

I've also struggled at this, but the docs describe that behavior:

> If a user has previously turned off a permission that you prompt for, the OS will advise your app to show a rationale for needing the permission. The optional rationale argument will show a dialog prompt only if necessary - otherwise the normal permission prompt will appear.

So if you wan't to have a notice for the User what for do you need the permission, it seems you need to use an alert in front of first Permission-Request.

*If anybody has another way, I would be glad to hear.*

Comment: Did you find a way to show rationale at first request too?

Answer (score 1):

check whether your  app already  has the permission, if permission is granted it won't show any popup