# React-native:- Location permission dialog is not working

Tags: react-native, permissions, geolocation, android-permissions

I want to enable location of my device(android pie). I have read the documentation of Permissions of react-native and then tried to implement it but every time it says "Location permission denied". I even tried to use external library(react-native-permissions) then it says:- "undetermined: User has not yet been prompted with a permission dialog". I have given the permissions(FINE_LOCATION and COARSE_LOCATION) in manifest also. I even tried to give permission manually in app permissions but still it says permission denied. How can i enable location.

Here is the code:

```
async requestLocationPermission() {
try {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    {
      title: "Example App",
      message: "Example App access to your location "
    }
  );
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    console.log("You can use the location");
    alert("You can use the location");
  } else {
    console.log("location permission denied");
    alert("Location permission denied");
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err);
}
}
```

calling it in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount(){
this.requestLocationPermission();
}
```

Comment: What is `targetSdkVersion ` inside `android/app/build.gradle` ?

Comment: 28 targetSdkVersion...buidtoolVersion is 28.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I did the same way. Added FINE_LOCATION and COARSE_LOCATION in AndroidManifest.xml file. And written the above code snippet as like you.

## Then I too got the **Location permission denied** message.

Then I opened AndroidStudio and Did clean and build.
Deleted the app from emulator and re run it, react-native run-android
Then the Location permission dialog came.

Comment: you can also clean it using this command:

 cd android && ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds alittle weird...

Try and open Google Maps. The dialog will sometimes appear.

Literally, that's my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the emulator, the location services do not work at all on Android emulators, unlike iOS which mocks it.

install  'react-native-device-info' and check if its an android emulator before using the location service

Answer (score 0):

After applying permission method if u are seeing msg like " **Location permission denied"or you are not able to see the Permission dialog.**.then reset your granted permissions .

1.If you are using an Emulator:For that run a cmd at your current project directory path in command prompt: run:" ***adb shell pm reset-permissions***"

2.If you are using your device then deny all permissions from setting .

this will reset your all given permission .And After that in my case i am able to see the permission dialog box and able to allow or deny the permissions by own.